# Where can I find implementation of the various improvements of K-nearest neighbors (KNN)?

Tags: machine-learning, python, algorithms, k-nn

I have been facing some challenges where traditional KNN algorithm perform well. I'd like to explore more advanced knn solutions. While researching possible solutions, I came across a paper titled
`"Improving K-nearest neighbor algorithm for classification tasks"` (https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1038/s41598-022-10358-x.pdf), which discusses several enhancements to the KNN algorithm.

The improvements mentioned in the paper are as follows:

1. KNN (K-nearest neighbor)
2. A-KNN (Adaptive K-nearest neighbor)
3. LA-KNN  (Locally adaptive K-nearest neighbor)
4. F-KNN (Fuzzy K-nearest    neighbor)
5. kM-KNN (K-means K-nearest neighbor)
6. W-KNN (Weighted    K-nearest neighbor)
7. H-KNN (Hassanat K-nearest neighbors)
8. GMD-KNN    (Generalized mean distance K-nearest neighbor)
9. M-KNN (Mutual    K-nearest neighbor)
10. EA-KNN (Ensemble approach K-nearest neighbor)

I have been unable to find simple implementations of these variants. Are there any standard libraries available, preferably in Python, that provide implementations for these KNN improvements?